# Criar trigger de registro

Tags: trigger

Trigger que ao excluir um registro de qualquer uma das tabelas de dimensão geradas pelo modelo que criou, elimine todos os registros vinculados no CUBO_EMPESTIMO.

Banco de Dados SQL.
Em anexo imagem do modelo https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFfQ8.jpg

Comment: Qual o banco de dados? Oracle? SQL? Por favor, complemente sua pergunta.

Comment: Banco de Dados SQL.